# Send notification to a device (ios or android) with custom API using Node.js

Tags: node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io, notifications

I'm trying to send notification when something is added inside my database using Socket.io with my custom API in Node.js but i don't know how can i send this kind of notification. In this case i'm sending a socket to all clients which contains a body, but now how can i make it appear regardless of operating system?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the notification providers like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/), you have to implement a logic that when your db updated then using the OneSignal APIs send the proper notofocation to the user.